# Haskell Data.List.Class and syntax

Tags: haskell, syntax, typeclass

I am trying to read the source code for the Haskell package Data.List.Class. (List-0.4.2). But I am stuck with some of the syntax.

Right at the beginning, it reads:

```
data ListItem l a =
    Nil |
    Cons { headL :: a, tailL :: l a }
```

I am not familiar with the syntax of the 3rd line. I guess that this last line is equivalent to `Cons a (l a)` ??. But I am not really sure. I noticed that the header of the file says: `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, TypeFamilies #-}`.

Then as I go on, there is a strange use of the `type` statement:  `type ItemM l :: * -> *`, which I couldn't understand.

```
Data.List.Class
-- | A class for list types. Every list has an underlying monad.
class (MonadPlus l, Monad (ItemM l)) => List l where
    type ItemM l :: * -> *
    runList :: l a -> ItemM l (ListItem l a)
    joinL :: ItemM l (l a) -> l a
    cons :: a -> l a -> l a
    cons = mplus . return
```

Can anyone help explain what these mean? I have a perfect understanding of Data.List, but this type class thing is not really clear to me.
Also I searched about wiki's, examples, and/or tutorials for using Data.List.{Class,Tree}, but there does not seem to be any, except the comments that come with the code. Any pointers here?

Thanks.

-- update --
The first answer (@Chris) helped me understand the Kind signature and the Record Syntax, which is really helpful. However, I still cannot make sense out of that piece of code overall in terms of how it captures/defines the behavior of a List and what value it adds to the familiar Data.List definitions. Here are some further details, where there are only two instance statements. Also the `Identity` term comes from `import Data.Functor.Identity (Identity(..))`. Can you please help explain what this is type class do to capture the characteristics of a list as we normally know it? Again, I searched it online but there is really no documentation for Data.List.Class except the code itself. Anyone knows?

Also, is there another example use of the `type` statement in the typeclass constraint similar to what's in this example? I searched learnyouahaskell.com/  (@Landei) but couldn't find such an example. I am assuming that the usage of `type` here is similar to how you would use `typedef`'s in C++ templates to define 'functions on types', right?

Thanks again.

```
instance List [] where
    type ItemM [] = Identity
    runList [] = Identity Nil
    runList (x:xs) = Identity $ Cons x xs
    joinL = runIdentity
    cons = (:)

instance Functor m => Functor (ListItem m) where
    fmap _ Nil = Nil
    fmap func (Cons x xs) = Cons (func x) (fmap func xs)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Record Syntax

This

```
data ListItem l a = Nil | Cons { headL :: a, tailL :: l a }
```

is called *record syntax*. You're correct when you guess that the structure is the same as if you'd typed

```
data ListItem l a = Nil | Cons a (l a)
```

However, you also get the two accessor functions:

```
headL :: ListItem l a -> a
headL (Cons a _) = a

tailL :: ListItem l a -> l a
tailL (Cons _ as) = as
```

Record syntax is syntactic sugar - here it saves you around 4 lines of code. You can pattern match in the normal way, as in the code directly above this paragraph, or you can use the record syntax in the pattern match:

```
safeHeadL :: ListItem l a -> Maybe a
safeHeadL Nil                = Nothing
safeHeadL (Cons {headL = a}) = Just a
```

Again, this is desugared into standard pattern matching.

### Kind Signatures

This

```
class (MonadPlus l, Monad (ItemM l)) => List l where
  type ItemM l :: * -> *
  runList :: l a -> ItemM l (ListItem l a)
  joinL   :: ItemM l (l a) -> l a

  cons :: a -> l a -> l a
  cons = mplus . return
```

is a *type family* declaration. The line

```
  type ItemM l :: * -> *
```

is a *kind signature*. When we say something has kind `*`, we mean that it's a base type, like `Int` or `Float`. To say that something has kind `* -> *` means that it is a *type constructor*, i.e. it takes a type and returns another type.

The `Maybe` type constructor has this kind signature:

```
Maybe :: * -> *
```

Remember that `Maybe` on its own isn't a type. It has to be given a type, and then it returns a type. Give it `Int` and you get `Maybe Int`. Give it `Double` and you get `Maybe Double`.

The type constructor `ItemM l` takes a type parameter (of kind `*`) and returns something of kind `*`. Note that since `l` is of kind `*`, you have

```
ItemM :: * -> * -> *
```

i.e. `ItemM` takes two types, and returns a type (equivalently, it takes one type and returns a unary type constructor).

By including the type declaration in the class, you impose the constraint that in all instances of the class, the `l` in `ItemM l` has to match up with the `l` in `List l`. It's impossible to create an instance of the class where these don't match up.

Comment: Good answer! I would have mentioned that record syntax helps to get a partially modified copy of a value, too. And here are some examples for record syntax: http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#record-syntax