# Haskell data.list.class usage

Tags: list, haskell, typeclass

This is a question on a usage issue with Data.List.Class (related to a previous question on [Haskell Data.List.Class and syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770733/haskell-data-list-class-and-syntax)).

Relevant segments of the code are listed below. From my understanding, this class is providing a type class interface or generalization to the Haskell list type, which could be really useful. However, I couldn't really find much documentation out there on the usage of this class. Does any one know a good tutorial?

Also, I have a technical/specific question regarding its usage and types. From the code, I would think that in the type class definition, runList and joinL are inverses of each other (in a certain sense).

```
-- other stuff omitted
import Data.Functor.Identity (Identity(..))

data ListItem l a =
    Nil |
    Cons { headL :: a, tailL :: l a }

Data.List.Class
-- | A class for list types. Every list has an underlying monad.
class (MonadPlus l, Monad (ItemM l)) => List l where
    type ItemM l :: * -> *
    runList :: l a -> ItemM l (ListItem l a)
    joinL :: ItemM l (l a) -> l a
    cons :: a -> l a -> l a
    cons = mplus . return

instance List [] where
    type ItemM [] = Identity
    runList [] = Identity Nil
    runList (x:xs) = Identity $ Cons x xs
    joinL = runIdentity
    cons = (:)

fromList :: List l => [a] -> l a
fromList = foldr cons mzero
```

First, I entered `joinL $ runList [1, 2, 3]` in emacs mode, but I got the following error:

```
Couldn't match type `ItemM (ListItem [])' with `Identity'
Expected type: ItemM (ListItem []) (ListItem [] Integer)
  Actual type: ItemM [] (ListItem [] Integer)
```

As it says, the expected and actual types do not match exactly. But I can't see why they should require different types in the first place. How are `runList :: l a -> ItemM l (ListItem l a)` and `joinL :: ItemM l (l a) -> l a` different in terms of their meaning or semantics?

Also, I tried a very simple function fromList in emacs mode as follows: `fromList [1,2,3]`, yet I got:

```
Ambiguous type variable `l0' in the constraint:
  (List l0) arising from a use of `fromList'
Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
In the expression: fromList [1, 2, 3]
In an equation for `it': it = fromList [1, 2, 3]
```

I am confused here why there is an ambiguity here, and how to add a type signature as the error message prompts. Anyone can help explain it?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

For last question: it may be several types that implements List typeclass, you should specify it if it will not be inferenced later. For example `fromList [1, 2, 3] :: [Int]` works fine.